# js in image title using fancybox gallery

Tags: fancybox

I am using fancybox(lightbox like js popup library) to show photo and it's title in popup. Photos are uploaded by user with supplied title. I also escaped the photo title when displaying the photo in html. the html tags are simple as:

`<a href="/files/909221123.large.JPG" title="sample image  &lt;script&gt;alert('test')&lt;/script&gt;"><img src="/files/909221123.medium.JPG"></a>`

As you can you see, the js tag in title is escaped. However, it runs regardlessly when displayed in fancybox popup - I click the photo which prompts a js alert popup then a fancybox popup with the photo.

That is a XSS problem for sure but I thought it is so obvious and fancybox shouldn't have this sorta problem at the first place. Did I do something wrong here? and How to fix it?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Fancybox is treating that string as HTML instead of text.

You could hack the plugin. There is code that handles the title such as...

```
return '<table id="fancybox-title-float-wrap" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td id="fancybox-title-float-left"></td><td id="fancybox-title-float-main">' + title + '</td><td id="fancybox-title-float-right"></td></tr></table>'
```

As you can see, by the time `title` is there, it has had its entities resolved.

Otherwise, you could strip out portions of the string which *look like* HTML tags with a regex.

Comment: would rather not hack the plugin directly..

and not sure if i can write a 100% safe regex as escaped html also runs fine.

Comment: in the return statement 'title' is the title value from the `<a title="&lt;script&gt;alert('test')&lt;/script&gt;">`. so it should be escaped but didn't. I test it under firebug with the following and it prints the unescaped html:   `console.log( $("<a title=\"&lt;script&gt;alert('test')&lt;/script&gt;\">").attr('title') );`